# Prevent Swing GUI from becoming unresponsive when invoking a method which is both accessing Swing components and is time-consuming

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

The following line:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(aComponent);
```

is making my GUI unresponsive.

When invoking this method to update the laf on a large portion of a GUI, it takes a lot of time, and so makes the GUI unresponsive during this operation.

Since this operation is manipulating the GUI, one can't use a SwingWorker for this either.
From the SwingWorker documentation:

> - Time-consuming tasks should not be run on the Event Dispatch Thread.
>     Otherwise the application becomes
>     unresponsive.
> - Swing components should be accessed on the Event Dispatch Thread
>     only.

The problem here though, is that the operation is accessing Swing components **and** is time-consuming.

Is there a good way to prevent this unresponsiveness?

Comment: Guessing that it takes so much time, because it is a large component tree ... can you call it on sub components instead, breaking the pauses in smaller pieces?

Comment: The essential question is **why** do you want to manually update this compon ent tree, when a correct MVC architecture would allow you to only update specific components by refreshing their model.

Comment: @Riduidel What I am doing is changing the fonts on all swing components. Changing the laf and updating the component tree seems like a smooth way of doing this, instead of having to change the font on all components manually.

Comment: How large is your component tree? Do you have thousands of components in there? Is it possible that some branches of your component tree are hidden instead of being disposed?

Comment: @jfpoilpret Many of the components are not visible at the same time, as I am using CardLayout on several places. However, none of the visible components are obsolete. There are probably around 100 components

Comment: 100 components shouldn't take any measurable time .. so the task is to track down if/where there's a bottleneck

Comment: [`jvisualvm`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is probably already on your machine.

Comment: @kleopatra it's rather around 200-300 components. It takes about 4 seconds for me to finish the operation. There doesn't seem to be a bottleneck anywhere, but I am investigating this further now.

Comment: @kleopatra you were right! The bottleneck was a datepicker which contained thousands of components. By not adding the datepicker, the time was reduced from 4 sec to 1 sec. However, as I would like the datepicker to update as well, the problem remains.

Comment: @Jens I tried this approach, and it worked. However, I could not make it work using the updateComponentTree method, as I would like to. I had to recursively loop through all subcomponents and call updateUI() on them manually (which is what updateComponentTree is ment to do for me) in a separate thread, which feels a bit like a hack more than a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you do is changing the L&F, and that might severely impact the appearance and usability of the GUI, ask yourself whether you really want the application to be responsive during that time. It may be better to display a message ("Please wait..." or something) using the [glass pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), and freeze the GUI while the L&F is updated.

Now, as others have suggested, you may want to investigate why updating the component tree is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest looking through your GUI to identify any custom or third-party components that contained a lot of sub-components or that had any unusual or inefficient method to revalidate itself.  It looks like that was the case, as you mentioned the date picker was a serious bottleneck.

You suggested splitting the calls to `updateComponentTree` into several sub-tasks that allow events to occur in between, which might be a 'hack' but isn't too bad, unless the change of font changes the sizes of elements and may cause the user to miss a button etc.

If possible, I would suggest looking at the code in the date picker component and see if you can rewrite it so that instead of hiding the components in the pop-up, it actually removes/disposes them, and recreates them when necessary.  This should have no noticeable effect on the responsiveness of the date picker when it's being used, but will certainly speed up component tree updates when the pop-up is not visible.